# What is the point of using a trivial exception class?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, exception

What is the point of using a trivial exception class? Why declare it at all? 
For example:
class DivideByZero {};

Comment: The more trivial the better. The type itself is the most important thing, and after that an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distinct exception classes allows more precise differentiation of exceptions which may be incurred. The exception type is meta-data enough to distinguish between different exception situations.

Answer (score 2):

Reasons that come to my mind:

1. Clear abstractions.
2. Easily understandable and maintainable code.